# Github Actions Pull Container From Private Google Artifacts Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-artifact-registry

This is a simple question, how to pull a container image from a private google artifacts registry? I have a service account (temporary) with owner access.

This is my code:

```html
jobs:
  my_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    container:
      image: asia-southeast2-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo/my-image:latest
      options: --user root
```

As far as I know, if pull from private docker hub, we can add like this

```html
jobs:
  my_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    container:
      image: my-docker-hub/my-image:latest
      options: --user root
      credentials:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

How can I pull from the private google artifacts registry?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three types of authentication can be used to access artifacts registry in GCP, but for your GH Action jobs you can [Using a service account key](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#key) for authentication

just save secrets on your github repository

```
DOCKER_USERNAME=_json_key_base64
DOCKER_PASSWORD=key.json (this key is generated when you are creating google service account)
```

> Notes: make sure your service account have role for accessing the artifactory

Comment: For those using workload identity federation in gh actions, oauth tokens will be the more convenient option. Username: `oauth2accesstoken` Password: `gcloud auth print-access-token` See link in answer for more details.